# Manipulando String while true PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, string

Estou fazendo um exercicio de notas de alunos, receber uma str com o nome do aluno, depois int para saber as notas(n1,n2,n3,n4).
Fiz um while true, entao ele sempre vai perguntar, ate o usuario pedir para sair, pois o programa cai perguntar se deseja continuar com s/n.

```
while True:
aluno_nome = str(input("Digite o nome do aluno:"))
aluno = print("Digite notas aluno.")
n1=int(input("Nota 1:"))
n2=int(input("Nota 2:"))
n3=int(input("Nota 3:"))
n4=int(input("Nota 4:"))
final = (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4
#print("Aluno ",aluno_nome,"\nNota Final:",media)
sai = str(input('\nDeseja continuar[S/N]?').lower())
while sai != 's' and sai != 'n':
    sai = str(input('Deseja continuar[S/N]?').lower())
if sai in 'n':
    break
print("\nAluno ",aluno_nome,"\nNota Final:",final)
```

Quero saber qual o metodo mais facil, de print no fim o nome de cada aluno, e a nota do mesmo, tipo aluno tal no tal, aluno tal nota tal.
Tenho q realmente criar uma variavel para cada nome e assim guardar cada das 4 notas dentro, mas nao consigo fazer isso mais "limpo" com o while true, e e fazer algum contador pra ir criando e armazenando o nome e a nota final do aluno.

Comment: Você quer mostrar ao final do laço uma lista com todos os alunos de input e sua média final? Seria isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar [dicionario](https://blog.alura.com.br/trabalhando-com-o-dicionario-no-python/) para salvar os dados de cada aluno, utilizar uma [lista](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460) para salva-los e quando o usuario terminar a digitação, você faz um iteração na lista de alunos para exibir o resultado final, ex:

```
# cria um array de alunos
ar_alunos = []

while True:
  al = {} # cria dicionario aluno vazio

  # salva nome do aluno
  al['aluno_nome'] = str(input("Digite o nome do aluno:"))

  print("Digite notas aluno.")
  n1=int(input("Nota 1:"))
  n2=int(input("Nota 2:"))
  n3=int(input("Nota 3:"))
  n4=int(input("Nota 4:"))

  #calcula media das notas
  al['media'] = (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4

  #salva aluno no array de alunos
  ar_alunos.append(al)

  sai = str(input('\nDeseja continuar[S/N]?').lower())
  while sai != 's' and sai != 'n':
      sai = str(input('Deseja continuar[S/N]?').lower())
  if sai in 'n':
      break


# printa todas as medias  
print()
print("# Relatorio de medias #")
for aluno in ar_alunos:
  print()
  print("Aluno ",aluno['aluno_nome'],"\nNota Final:",aluno['media'])
```